# WebStorageはサーバー側で取得できないのでしょうか

Tags: cookie

WebStorageはCookieのように毎回http通信に乗っからないからセキュアだと聞いて使い始めたのですが、逆にサーバー側でWebStorageのデータを取得するにはどうしたらよいのかわからなくて困っています。
javascriptで結構ゴリゴリ作ってしまったのですが、、、もしかして無理なのでしょうか?

もし可能であれば例を出していただけると助かります。

ruby on railsとネイティブのphpでの扱いかたが知りたいです。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: サーバー側でWebStorageのデータを取得するのは無理です。

Comment: やはりそういうやつではないんですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

クライアント側からバックグラウンドでPOSTするしかありません。
websocketでクエリを出してpostしてもらったり、何らかのアクションをきっかけにpostする事になります。

```
$.ajax( url: hostUrl, type:'POST', data:localStorage.getItem(key) );
```